# "leave us kids alone"

Tags: grammaticality

From the lyrics to [Another Brick in the Wall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_Brick_in_the_Wall):

What is the grammatical construct in *leave us kids alone* or *leave them kids alone*?

> Teachers leave them kids alone. 
>   Hey teacher leave us kids alone

Is it short for *leave them, the kids, alone* and *leave us, the kids, alone*, respectively? I have seen the construct with *them [noun]* in other contexts, too, but can't find examples as it's hard to google.

Is this proper English? Are there phrases with a similar grammatical construct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *leave **them** kids alone* part is definitely ungrammatical, as is the first chorus  line [*We Don't Need No Education*](http://www.hotlyrics.net/lyrics/P/Pink_Floyd/We_Don_t_Need_No_Education.html) (the former should be ***those*** kids, and the latter uses the much-reviled [double negative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2232/are-double-negatives-proper-english-e-g-i-dont-know-nothing)).

Per [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/30251/2637) on a related ELU question, using *"them"* as an "article" is *non-standard* (but not uncommon in speech, particularly with the less well-educated, or in "facetious" usages).

There's nothing ungrammatical about *leave us kids alone* - if there were, you wouldn't expect to see written references to things that might [help us writers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a%20wobbly%20table%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22help%20us%20writers%22&oq=%22help%20us%20writers%22&gs_l=serp.3...5140.8819.1.9089.16.16.0.0.0.1.139.1239.12j4.16.0...0.0...1c.1.3.psy-ab.WMB_S-_-A4U&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42553238,bs.1,d.d2k&fp=1128f60b3d5eaf47&biw=1381&bih=848), for example.

In such constructions, the [optional] "class/category name" after *"us"* applies to *all of us* - it doesn't select *kids* or *writers* from a larger group. The context inherently implies that *"we"* are all *kids, writers, whatever.*

Comment: Interesting that there is a difference, grammatically speaking, between *us kids* and *them kids*.

Comment: @gerrit: I was thinking about mentioning that in the answer itself. Although there *is* a grammatical difference (*us kids* is "proper English" and *them kids* isn't), the way they're juxtaposed in the song lyrics (and the fact that the title itself is non-standard) give us the general sense that *us kids* might not be quite "kosher" either. But I decided that was a bit peripheral, so I contented myself with just showing via a Google Books link that even *published writers* have no problem writing of *us writers*.

Comment: @gerrit: As a general rule, _us kids_ would include the speaker, and _them kids_ would not. For example, _Todd said to the bully, "Leave them kids alone."_ means that Todd told the bully to stop what he was doing. In that context, Todd might even be an adult. If Todd says _"Leave us kids alone,"_ then I would presume Todd was numbered among the victims.

Comment: @J.R.: No question. The speaker *must* be one of "us" in such constructions. But in a heated public political debate, say, I suppose someone could say *"There's nothing wrong with us coloured lesbian teenage mothers, you know!"*. Without necessarily implying too much about *how many others* there might be in "our gang"! :)

Comment: 'tis the first two lines containing the double negative(s), not the title.  *Another Brick in the Wall (pt II)* has no negatives at all

Comment: @mcalex: You're quite right, of course. I've edited to reflect, but left the capitalisation for that line because lots of us *think of* the chorus first line as the title (on account of the *real* title is *(Part 2)* of three tracks with that same name).

Answer (score 0):

There are two voices in the song.

One is the narrator ('Pink') who is commenting on the education system.  He is the one responsible for 'Leave them kids alone'.

The other 'voice' belongs to the children in the system.  Their lyric is 'leave us kids alone'.

The 'us' in the second part makes sense when you consider that there is a whole choir of students singing that part, and the references in the film clip indicate that the entire school (multiple classrooms, at least) are all of one voice in the matter.