# ‘Of all us’ vs ‘of all of us’

Tags: prepositions

- God is the savior *of all us*.
- God is the savior *of all of us*.

Do they mean the same thing? Asking because the second one has two *of*. Is it okay to use it twice in a sentence?

Comment: The first one is simply wrong. Only "all of us" is acceptable.

Comment: Or the inverted form 'us all'.

Comment: But is using ‘of’ twice in a sentence (like the second one) correct too? Daniel Roseman just used it once.

Comment: I would say "God is the savior for all of us"

Comment: "X is the Y **of us all**" is the right expression.

Comment: Related questions: [“Except for us” or “Except us”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/18001/9161), [Made us fool VS Made fool of us](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/237678/9161), [“leave us kids alone”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/2826/9161)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using _of_ twice in this context.

Answer (score 1):

God is the savior of all us. Incorrect

**God is the savior of us all.**  Correct

**God is the savior of all of us.** Correct

Answer (score 1):

The phrase is "God is the savior *of*... [object]."

"All people" is an object. "All of us" is an object.

"Us" on its own is a pronoun, and although it is in the objective case, it does not work in this construction. Similarly "me" or "you" would be incorrect. You would have to rewrite it to be possessive: "God is *our/my/your* savior." Or you could use the object "us all," which does work in this construction.